# In Excel is there any way to turn columns separated by "Text to Colums" into their own rows? Example given inside

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[1. Original table with concatenated fields & 2. table after use of "Text to Columns"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4t7y.png)

[3. Is this even possible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdSk8.png)

Hello! I'm pretty new to the fancier formula side of Excel and I have a large amount of data that has been saved in concatenated fields. The Contact column, contains all contacts for a single entity/hospital, and I have separated these contacts into their own columns (See images 1-2). What I want to know is if there's any shorthand way to create additional row items that contain the same Hospital, Address etc., but transpose these Contacts from columns into rows (image 3.... this was done by hand just to give an example). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Power Query? (Get and Transform)
You might have to do a download and install to set it up in Excel 2010 though.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-a-column-of-text-Power-Query-5282d425-6dd0-46ca-95bf-8e0da9539662

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Pivot Table. Get the data into a pivot table and put your contacts in the "values" list.

Use this to guide you how to use a pivot table:

[Pivotable Tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2016 there is a Text to Columns button on the Data tab which fires up a wizard that will do what you are askin for.